# Deadlock in this method?

Tags: concurrency, thread-synchronization

While going through the [Unreliable guide to locking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/kernel-hacking/locking.html#deadlock), I found this line

Deadlocks are problematic, but not as bad as data corruption. Code which grabs a read lock, searches a list, fails to find what it wants, drops the read lock, grabs a write lock and inserts the object has a race condition.

My problem is I don't see how. My understanding is that you cannot acquire a write lock before all others have dropped a read lock. In this case, code would acquire a write lock only when there are no readers currently accessing that area.

Comment: What guarantees that no other thread will grab a write lock once you've dropped the read lock?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

Comment: Before inserting if you're looking up the value again after taking the write lock then there is no problem.

Comment: @Mat, This is exactly what is confusing to me. My understanding of write_lock is this:
while(test_and_set(0,lock_bit)!=1);
where test_and_set is an atomic instr. 
The point is that the write lock is taken only if no other thread already has it and is not holding a read lock either, so I am not sure TOCTOU applies here.

Comment: There is a "gap" between when you release the read lock and acquire the write lock. You don't know what (if anything) happened to the data in between.